# Finding the $f(7)$ value in an exponential decay for caffeine consumed over time

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Following up on [G Cab's excellent reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920441/794754) to the MSE question entitled *"How to write equation for half-life of caffeine consumed over time?"*, I'd like to find the half-life value at $t=6$. The user provided a nice plot, which I've been trying to match up with my calculations.

### My Attempt

Using the final line in red of the integral and $\lambda  = \frac{{\ln 2}}{6}$

\begin{align*}&\color{red}{\frac{1}{\lambda}}([0\leqslant t \lt1](e^{\lambda t}-1)+\color{red}{[1\leqslant t](e^\lambda-1))e^{-\lambda t}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{6}\right)}\left(e^{\left(\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{6}\right)}-1\right)e^{-\left(\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{6}\right)\left(6\right)}\\
&=0.53\\
\end{align*}

This appears to match the value in the plot, but would this be correct? Also, would there be a better way to calculate this?

**Edit:** solution seen below.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
# using the calculated y values for f(1)=0.944, etc.
ypoints = np.array([0.0, 0.944, 0.841, 0.749, 0.667, 0.594, 0.530, 0.472, 0.420, 0.374, 0.333, 0.297, 0.265])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, linestyle = '-')
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("f(t)")
plt.title("Half-life of caffeine consumer over time")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This simplifies considerably: 
$$
\frac{3 \cdot \sqrt[6]{2} - 1}{\ln 2},  
$$
which is approximated by the decimal value you have written.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the half-life value at $t=6$" as half-life refers to an exponential decay, which only begins after $t=1$, so the value at $t = 1 + 6 = 7$ is when we expect half of the caffeine to have decayed. Sure enough: $f(7) \approx 0.4722$, which is half of $f(1) \approx 0.9444$.

Comment: The function $f(t)$ in the other post is not "half-life of caffeine consumer" as you've labelled it here, but rather "amount of caffeine in the consumer with respect to time" but divided by $100$ mg (which is why the graph $y$-axis is between $0$ and $1$). The *half-life of caffeine* is the $6$ hour number quoted by the OP in that thread. This value is physiologically based and has nothing to do with how quickly the consumer takes in the caffeine (though I am sure the value here is just a somewhat random choice made by the author of the problem).